# How to solve calling Startup.cs from Program.cs?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, startup

**EDIT**

I'm using Blazor WASM project. I'm trying to create an Indexed DB to my project with TG.Blazor.IndexedDB NuGet Package. I create Startup.cs in my project. I have a few error in Program.cs & Startup.cs.

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IComponentsApplicationBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Starup.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TG.Blazor.IndexedDB;


 namespace WebApplication
{
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIndexedDB(dbStore =>
        {
            dbStore.DbName = "TheFactory";
            dbStore.Version = 1;

            dbStore.Stores.Add(new StoreSchema
            {
                Name = "Employees",
                PrimaryKey = new IndexSpec { Name = "id", KeyPath = "id", Auto = true },
                Indexes = new List<IndexSpec>
                {
                    new IndexSpec{Name="firstName", KeyPath = "firstName", Auto=false},
                    new IndexSpec{Name="lastName", KeyPath = "lastName", Auto=false}

                }
            });
            dbStore.Stores.Add(new StoreSchema
            {
                Name = "Outbox",
                PrimaryKey = new IndexSpec { Auto = true }
            });
        });
    }
//error here 
    public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.AddComponent<App>("app");
    }
}
 }
```

> Error CS1061  'WebAssemblyHost' does not contain a definition for 'Run' and no accessible extension method 'Run' accepting a first argument of type 'WebAssemblyHost' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> Error CS0103  The name 'BlazorWebAssemblyHost' does not exist in the current context

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TG.Blazor.IndexedDB;


 namespace WebApplication
{
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
       
        // error at Run()
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static WebAssemblyHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        //error at BlazorWebAssemblyHost
       BlazorWebAssemblyHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
           .UseBlazorStartup<Startup>();
}
}
```

**What I have tried:**

[Tg.Blazor.IndexedDB](https://github.com/wtulloch/Blazor.IndexedDB)

[Missing startup.cs program.cs .Net Core Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139801/missing-startup-cs-program-cs-net-core-razor)

Comment: Try `WebHost` instead.

Comment: @JevonKendon I have tried & still error

Comment: Not sure. I just ran ` dotnet new blazorserver -o BlazorApp --no-https` to generate a new blazor project. `Host` is found. I might suggest you start there, and update the generated code.

Comment: From https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/create

Comment: You have __2x__ `.Build().RunAsync()`. That can't be right.

Comment: Seems like you merged 2 examples, or that you are confusing Server.Program.cs and Client.Program.cs .

Comment: @HenkHolterman Before this, `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` but error `
Error CS1061 'WebAssemblyHost' does not contain a definition for 'Run' and no accessible extension method 'Run' accepting a first argument of type 'WebAssemblyHost' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Im not sure but I saw a few blazor project that use Startup.cs & Program.cs. Im trying to create Indexeddb in blazor using NuGet Package but having problem here in the Program.cs

Comment: "I saw a few blazor project" - Blazor comes in two varieties with very different Program/Startup logic.

Comment: You're pulling code from Blazor Server and trying to ram it into Web Assembly.   `WebAssemblyHostBuilder` is the host builder for WASM. `Host` is in ` Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`, but I'm pretty sure it specific to Server.  What's in Startup that you want to run?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have edit & insert the Program.cs & Startup.cs code

Answer (score 1):

This is the Splash page for Reshiru.Blazor.IndexDB.

It's **DEPRECIATED**, out of date, and stale.  In my book that means don't go near it.

[image]

Comment: ok noted & I have tested with TG.Blazor & have problem like above